# How does Solidity implement C3 linearization?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

The [solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization) does not offer a lot of insights into their implementation of the `C3 linearization` to resolve methods in a multiple inheritance scenario. There it states that

> You have to list the direct base contracts in the order from “most base-like” to “most derived”. Note that this order is the reverse of the one used in Python.

The `C3`-algorithm in python or in the [explanation on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) uses the recursive linearization `L(C) := [C] + merge(L(P1), L(P2),..., L(Pn))`, where `P1,...Pn` are the parent classes of `C`. The `+` is list-concatenation and `merge(list_1, list_2, ..., list_n)` is a list that is created iteratively: It starts with (i.e. initializes) an empty results list `M`. Then it goes through its member lists, picks up the head (say `H`) of the first list, whose head is not in the tail (i.e. anything except the head) of any other list, then appends it to `M` , removes `H` from all the lists where it occurs as a head and then repeats until all member lists have been used up or until a conflict appears.

My understanding is that solidity uses this same algorithm, except in reverse. Correct me if I'm wrong, but that would be

```
L[C] = reversemerge(L[P1], L[P2], ..., L[Pn]) + [C]
```

where the `reversemerge(list_1, ..., list_n)` starts with an empty list `M` and then successively fills it with classes as follows: It goes through the lists from back to front and picks up the "tail" (say `T`) from the first list in reverse order (i.e. starting from `n`, `n-1`, ... to `1`) that is not in the "head" (i.e. everything but the "tail") of any of the lists. (The "tail" is the last entry, so it is in general different from the abovementioned tail. Same for "head".) Then it inserts `T` at position 0 of `M` (prepends(?)) and removes `T` from all the lists where it was in the "tail". Then repeat as above.

But this algorithm does not seem to be the right one. `Solidity 0.8.4` threw a linearization error at me for the following (admittedly complicated) directed acyclic inheritance graph (Edit: I simplified the example a little bit):

```
contract Status {}
contract Caller {}
contract CallbackHash {}
contract ImplementResult is CallbackHash, Caller, Status {}
contract MainContract is Caller, Status {}
contract MainWithImplementing is Caller, CallbackHash, ImplementResult, MainContract {}
```

I do not encounter any conflicts when going through the algorithm by hand:

```
L(ImplementResult) = reversemerge(L(CallbackHash), L(Caller), L(Status)) + [ImplementResult]
                           = reversemerge([CallbackHash], [Caller], [Status]) + [ImplementResult]
                           = [CallbackHash, Caller, Status, ImplementResult]

L(MainContract) = reversemerge(L(Caller), L(Setter)) + [MainContract]
                = [Caller, Setter, MainContract]

L(MainWithImplementing) = reversemerge(L(Caller), L(CallbackHash),  L(ImplementResult), L(MainContract)) + [MainWithImplementing]
                        = reversemerge([Caller], [CallbackHash], [CallbackHash, Caller, Status, ImplementResult], [Caller, Setter, MainContract]) + [MainWithImplementing]
                        = [CallbackHash, Caller, Status, ImplementResult, MainContract, MainWithImplementing]
```

But solidity throws `TypeError: Linearization of inheritance graph impossible`. It would be great to get a better error message than this one.

Edit: I figured out how to resolve the Error by now, namely by switching the class-order in `contract ImplementResult is Caller, Status, CallbackHash {}`. But I still do not see why C3-linearization should have a problem with the former version.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this:

`contract ImplementResult is CallbackHash, Caller, Status {}`

requires CallbackHash, Caller in that order. Whereas this:

`contract MainWithImplementing is Caller, CallbackHash, ImplementResult, MainContract {}`

requires the opposite order Caller, CallbackHash. It is impossible to satisfy both requirements simultaneously. Your amended ImplementResult fixes this by switching the order. Your by hand version has the wrong ordering for MainWithImplementing.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, yes it has a wrong ordering and I figured it out. But when I want to avoid inheritance issues, it would be great to know the linearization rule. I thought I understood the rule, but in this case it doesn't seem to hold. It seems to go depth first, but that would not be C3 or would it?

Comment: I believe the Solidity algorithm is the same as the Python one except that `A is B, C` gives the ordering A -> C -> B . This is the opposite ordering of B and C to Python where `class A(B, C)` would give A -> B -> C. However, other than this the merge algorithm is the same. In particular there is no reversemerge picking from the tails, it's just merge taking always from the heads of the lists.